# Named capture group within optional non-capturing group

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have the below PowerShell code:

```
$input = 'ADM:Dev_ControllerStore_103:1:2'
$pattern = '^(?<UID>\S+)\:(?<DB>\S+)\:(?<AppId>\d+)(?:\:(?<LicNr>\d+))?$'
if ( $input -match $pattern ) {
    $Matches
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
DB                             1
AppId                          2
UID                            ADM:Dev_ControllerStore_103
0                              ADM:Dev_ControllerStore_103:1:2
```

Whilst I'd expect this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
DB                             1
AppId                          2
UID                            ADM:Dev_ControllerStore_103
LicNr                          2
0                              ADM:Dev_ControllerStore_103:1:2
```

i.e. for `LicNr` to be included in the output.

Note: The output I'm getting is the expected output for input string: `'ADM:Dev_ControllerStore_103:1'` ... and that works correctly.

If I change the regex to make the last non capturing group non-optional, or I remove the non-capturing group all works correctly for the longer input string; but obviously these then don't cater for the version where there's only 3 values rather than 4.

Am I missing something in my understanding, or is this a bug in PowerShell?

Note: I have a workaround (~ `$a,$b,$c,$d = $input -split ':'`), so this question is just for academic interest.

Comment: Are you sure you would expect `AppId` AND `LicNr` being `2` for the input `ADM:Dev_ControllerStore_103:1:2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\S` pattern matches any non-whitespace characters, including `:` and digits. You might fix the pattern by using the lazy `\S+?` pattern, `'^(?<UID>\S+?):(?<DB>\S+?):(?<AppId>\d+)(?::(?<LicNr>\d+))?$'`, but  may also use a more precise pattern that will use patterns more tailored to the input you have:

```
^(?<UID>\w+):(?<DB>\w+):(?<AppId>\d+)(?::(?<LicNr>\d+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3CUID%3E%5Cw%2B%29%3A%28%3F%3CDB%3E%5Cw%2B%29%3A%28%3F%3CAppId%3E%5Cd%2B%29%28%3F%3A%3A%28%3F%3CLicNr%3E%5Cd%2B%29%29%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=ADM%3ADev_ControllerStore_103%3A1%3A2%0D%0AADM%3ADev_ControllerStore_103%3A1&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<UID>\w+)` - Group UID: one or more word chars
- `:` - a colon
- `(?<DB>\w+)` - Group DB:  one or more word chars
- `:` - a colon
- `(?<AppId>\d+)` - Group AppId: one or more digits
- `(?::(?<LicNr>\d+))?` - an optional group: a `:` and then Group LicNr: 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Ah of course; I'd not paid attention the the start of the string / didn't even consider revising the `\S`; thank-you; I've now amended my code to use `[^\:]` to match any non-colons there.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Good, also, if you know there can be no spaces, you may use `[^\s:]`. Please do NOT escape `;` as it is never special in any regex flavor.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to split on `:` and have an optional part at the end, make your quantifiers before that option non-greedy:

```
$input = 'ADM:Dev_ControllerStore_103:1:2'
$pattern = '^(?<UID>\S+?)\:(?<DB>\S+?)\:(?<AppId>\d+?)(?:\:(?<LicNr>\d+))?$'
if ( $input -match $pattern ) {
    $Matches
}
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                  
DB                             Dev_ControllerStore_103                                                
AppId                          1                                                                      
UID                            ADM                                                                    
LicNr                          2                                                                      
0                              ADM:Dev_ControllerStore_103:1:2
```